# Which encoding should I use with TeXShop on a Mac?

Tags: texshop, input-encodings

TeXShop seems to default to 'Western (ISO Latin 9)', but a template I've been using is defaulting to 'Western (Mac OS Roman)'.  I'm using a package

Which encoding should I use with TeXShop on a Mac?

NB I'm using TeXShop for undergraduate mathematics assignments in english only.

Comment: I've thought better about putting two questions in one - I've moved the second question to another question!  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281831/will-i-get-trouble-if-i-use-packages-with-different-encodings

Comment: I see nothing in `tma.sty` that forces you to a particular encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the encoding for a file by adding a suitable string at the beginning:

### MacOS Roman

```
% !TEX encoding = MacOSRoman
```

### Latin-9

```
% !TEX encoding = IsoLatin9
```

### UTF-8

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
```

If TeXShop sees one of these lines, it will not use the default encoding set in the preferences for the file, but the one specified. You need not remember them: go to the menu Macros>Encoding and choose the encoding you want in the window that appears.

They correspond, in the same order, to

```
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and the corresponding declaration *must* be issued in the LaTeX main document.

I recommend having the introductory string in the older files and then changing the default encoding to UTF-8.