# Will I get trouble if I use packages with different encodings?

Tags: texshop, input-encodings

Will I get trouble if I use packages with different encodings?

I'm using TeXShop, with a [package](https://github.com/spdegabrielle/OU-LaTeX-TMA-package) in Western (ISO Latin 9), but the template file I am using with it is in Western (Mac OS Roman).

(Based on the comments below I don't think any non-ascii characters are in use.)

Comment: I see nothing in `tma.sty` that suggests a particular encoding.

Comment: @egreg it shows up in the save dialog in TeXShop. I don't know how to check encodings in github.

Comment: Use UTF-8 for all files and your life will be easier.

Comment: It's possible to do that but really this century you shouldn't be using an OS-specific encoding like Mac OS Roman, nor an 8bit ISO latin encoding like latin 9. The overwhelming majority of package files are in ascii so work as any (well, most latex supported) encoding with no change.

Comment: tma.sty has no non-ascii characters that I can see.

Comment: Should the answer be: 'you probably won't have any trouble using different encodings as long as none of the files use characters outside the ascii range. In general, you should change all your files to UTF-8 to avoid future problems.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you might get into trouble if you use packages with different encodings, because when TeX reads a file, it records the byte(s) that make up each character; the byte or byte sequence is interpreted as a character at the point where it is typeset. Example (save this file as UTF-8):

```
\documentclass{standalone} %-*-coding: utf-8-*-
\usepackage[applemac,latin9,utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\foo}{£}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  UTF-8 & \inputencoding{utf8} \foo \\
  Latin 9 & \inputencoding{latin9} \foo \\
  Mac Roman & \inputencoding{applemac} \foo \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: £ in UTF-8, Latin 9 and Mac Roman]

The definition of the command `\foo` contains the two bytes that make up the character `£` in the UTF-8 encoding (because I said to save the file as UTF-8). It's equivalent to

```
\newcommand{\foo}{^^c2^^a3}
```

When the command is used while the input encoding is UTF-8, you get the character £. When the command is used while the input encoding is Latin 9, you get Â£, because `^^c2` is Â in Latin 9 and `^^a3` is £. When the command is used while the input encoding is Mac Roman, you get `$\neg$` (which forces math mode, so there's a compilation error) for `^^c2` and £ for `^^a3`.

It's ok as long as any of the commands whose definitions contain non-ASCII characters are only used in the encoding they were intended for (which includes the case where you never use them at all, e.g. if they're translations of some text for a language you don't use). But otherwise the characters won't be typeset as intended. This is why most packages do, and all packages should, stick to ASCII characters and use explicit ways of designating other characters (e.g. `\pounds` instead of `£` in whatever encoding).

As others have remarked, [Open University TMA LaTeX package](https://github.com/spdegabrielle/OU-LaTeX-TMA-package) sticks to pure ASCII, so you'll be fine. Maybe your program shows it to you as Latin 9 because it shows this rather than ASCII by default.

Note: this answer applies to the TeX/LaTeX proper. Other systems such as LuaLaTeX may behave differently.