# Unicode char not set up for use with latex

Tags: tex-core, unicode, input, input-encodings

I am trying to display something like

- ó
- í
- ö
- ß

... basicalliy European alphabet Italy, France, Spain, Portugal, Germany. Should not be too hard.

I load this package `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. As far as I know `utf-8` contains these characters.
But, when I compile, I get

> Unicode char not set up for use with latex

And `Fórum` turns out to be nothing more then a `F`.
Why is that?

Comment: Does your editor saver in UTF8? And did you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: @Bernard loading the package you suggested did not do the trick. Where do i chose saver utf-8?

Comment: What editor are you using? (TeXworks, TeXMaker, TeXshop, WinEdt, etc?)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am using TeXshop

Comment: Okay, perhaps [Which encoding should I use with TeXShop on a Mac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281826) can help.